# Is possible to run http and https server with same port no in node.js using express?

Tags: node.js

I have two server HTTP and HTTPS with key.Once I authenticated then I need to change Http to HTTPS at the same port..

```
var httpsoptions={
key:fs.readFileSync('./keys/twc-key.pem'),
cert:fs.readFileSync('./keys/twc-cert.pem')
};

var webServer = express();    
var websecure = express(httpoptions);
```

Here I need to maintain same port for both Http and Https how is possible?

Comment: Why on the same port? HTTP should run on 80 and HTTPS should run on 443. I don't think it's possible to run both on the same port.

Comment: Surely it is the same address, not port? Serving two different protocols on the same address AND port sounds like a no go. Serving on the same address, but e.g. on 80 and 443 for HTTP and HTTPS is easily configurable in apache (either directly in the main server or in vhost), and it is possibly a good idea to put node.js server behind apache anyway.

Comment: Makes the most sense to serve node behind nginx, as it uses the same library to handle asynchronous flow (libuv). Nginx is also lighter and fast. Apache is still great but node simply won't use the additional features apache provides, therefore adding unnecessary bulk. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: thanks for your reply.my question is,the **res.redirect("https://home") ** is must or not? Is possible to auto redirect from http to https url?when authenticated the credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Use Nginx as a reverse proxy**

- You can enable HTTPs on nginx, and proxy your node application through nginx.

### **Use the express-vhost middleware**

- Use express-vhost and host https on a subdomain
- eg. `https://secure.url.com`
- or `https://login.url.com`

### **Use port 443**

- Easier yet!
- 443 is accepted as a default port for https by basically all browsers. Some call it deprecated, but I've seen nothing supporting this claim.
- 443 is still accepted as the default port for https.

### **Host everything over https**

- Many sites do this already
- Prevents session hijacking
- Prevents token hijacking
- Prevents MITM attacks
- Even if you just have the log in secure, afterward your cookies are in plain text in your http header. An attacker could steal the session cookie and hijack the users session.

Comment: How does this answer the original question, which I must admit is poorly formulated?

Comment: Well I'm under the assumption that you're just trying to implement http and https in the same application. Which is totally possible, however you cannot host 2 servers on the same port without vhost, which means you'll have to use a separate domain or sub domain for https, many sites do this(see my example). You can also host on 443, as browsers look for https here. These solutions are only practical if a reverse proxy or frontend server cannot be implemented, as node is best used behind a proxy like nginx. If you want to "change" a http session to https, you simply cannot in node.

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question please provide more detail to what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply..I want to change http ("http://home/") to https ("https://home/") automatically while after login with credentials.can you explain in detail.Is res.redirect("https://home/") is must or not ?

Comment: Honestly, with most processors AMD, Intel, and ARM6 and above. Have dedicated encryption instruction sets. Encrypting and decrypting on the fly is a very well optimized factor of openSSL and most SSL libraries. If you're worried about the extra resources the processing strain is very minimal for decent key sizes(~256bit). You might as well just use HTTPS solely.

Comment: If you insist on implementing HTTP and HTTPS, you should look at it this way. HTTP and HTTPS are technically _separate_ services, they each have their own defined paths. HTTPS doesn't just wrap sockets for HTTP. What you should do is on the HTTP(port 80) server you should host `home/` then check cookies in the clients request header, if they belong to a logged-in session then respond with an HTTP redirect to `/home` hosted on the HTTPS(port 443) server. Just make sure you don't include the redirect on the HTTPS server or you'll throw your client into a redirect infinite loop.