# NodeJs SSL on Gandi Simple Hosting: listen EACCES

Tags: node.js, ssl

I am pretty desperate, the following problem is haunting me for weeks now:
I am encountering the "listen EACCES" error on my Gandi Simple Hosting instance, when i try to run my NodeJs instance on port 443.
Is there something i did wrong i didn't know about?
I must say that I'm very new to the whole hosting topic.

I am using NodeJs with Express, here's the relevant code:

```
var express = require('express')
  , https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./scrt/apiKey.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./scrt/apiCrt.crt')
};
//....
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 443);
//.....
https.createServer(options, app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
});
```

Do you have any idea what i miss?
Maybe i have to change some configuration for the port 443?
I was just told by Gandi, that port 443 is the right port for SSL, so actually it should work...

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Edit: No one here ever had the same problems with SSL on nodejs? :/

Comment: I do have the same issue... I have everything setup and it works on my machine, but not on gandi.net simple hosting

Comment: And you have an instance of size "M" or bigger right?

Answer (score 2):

In Gandi Simple Hosting, SSL is done by a SSL offloader, you do not need to handle it by yourself.

The ssl offloader then redirects all incoming trafic (HTTP and HTTPS) on the instance's 8080 port.

To see if a request is secure, I bet you could look at the X-Forwarded-Proto header.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have had the answer from Gandi support team: all the traffic, SSL and not SSL is routed to the port 8080.

I still could not get it working since nodejs needs to handle one port for both traffic and it is not straightforward, see these posts

- [Is possible to run http and https server with same port no in node.js using express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748625/is-possible-to-run-http-and-https-server-with-same-port-no-in-node-js-using-expr)
- [A node.js proxy that accepts HTTP and HTTPS traffic on the same port.](https://gist.github.com/bnoordhuis/4740141)

**EDIT:** @themouette is right, it works out of the box, no need to handle it in nodejs, but you need to activate the certificate on the domain level, but **from your instance's admin page**, which is not written in the docs.